# search logic in Rails, making it more precise hopefully without a gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

is there a way to improve the search logic in Rails. for example, currently if i search 'red leather' the search matches red OR leather. How could you improve the search logic so that if i search 'red leather' I don't get 'red dog' but say 'red leather coat'. Ideally I would like to do this without a gem. I am using MySQL with rails 4.

an example of my search function is here

```
 if params[:search_term].present? && params[:search_term].length > 1
   @candidates = @candidates.where("title like ?","%#{params[:search_term]}%")
 end
```

UPDATE

I search `'BLACK cat' (There are no black cats in my db), and i am yielded these...

```
1m Single Bolster Black Velvet 
1m Straight Back Black Velvet 
70cm Straight Back Black Velvet
```

the inclusion of cat should negate these results...

Comment: I'd use a gem. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: because what i am trying to achieve is so simple.. surely

Comment: I neglected to answer further because it seems like your code contradicts your description of the results. %search term% in SQL should indeed only find substrings within `title` that contain "search term". I don't see a problem with your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try splitting your search term by spaces and calling where for each of them. In Arel this will keep adding filters to your sql with AND...

Assuming your model is called Candidate

```
query = Candidate
params[:search_term].split(' ').each do |term|
  query = query.where('title like %?%', term)
end
# check it's worked
puts query.to_sql
result = query.all
```

This should do what you're after. 'red leather' should find 'a red coat made of leather' or 'a leather coat with red pockets'

Although, as a matter of coding practise, this should really be a method in your model, not in the controller. Like so:

```
def Candidate.search(search_term)
  query = Candidate
  params[:search_term].split(' ').each do |term|
    query = query.where('title like %?%', term)
  end
  result = query.all
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def search
  @candidates = Candidate.search(params[:search_term])
end
```

This means that you could then use the method elsewhere, for instance, as part of a rake task, or in the console, which is useful for debugging if you find a problem with it, or want to refine your search method.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL works fine, take a look:

http://ideone.com/Nr1E26

```
create table tbl(name varchar(20));
insert into tbl(name) values("red dog");
insert into tbl(name) values("red leather");
insert into tbl(name) values("red leather coat");

select * from tbl WHERE name LIKE "%red leather%";
```

output:

```
red leather
red leather coat
```

Comment: Your update doesn't jive but in your new "update" are you saying, it has to equal 'black cat' or nothing at all?

Comment: you know what man. I think I had confused myself more than anything. you're right =there above. Thanks